# How to detect bluetooth device connection in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I am trying to show toast message when the device is connected to bluetooth. To do this, I made a receiver and wrote the code as below, but there is no response when a Bluetooth device is connected.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

mainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

val bluetoothBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val bleOnOffBtn:ToggleButton = findViewById(R.id.bluetooth_on_off_btn)

       
        var action  = intent?.getAction()
      
           // toast not showing for connecting and disconnecting device
            if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)){
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext,
                    "Device is now Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }else if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext,
                    "Device is disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
    }
}

    val filter = IntentFilter().apply{
        addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED)
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
    }
    registerReceiver(bluetoothBroadcastReceiver, filter)
}
```

What part of the code below should be modified to show toast when a Bluetooth device is connected?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because I didn't ask for permission grant.
I write By inserting the code below into MainActivity.kt to allow permission, the desired event occurs when the device is connected.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT), 2)
```